# Why is my quick sort goofing up?

Tags: javascript, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to implement the memory intensive implementation of the quicksort, the first sort [the first chunk of code described here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort)

```
function quickSort(arr){
   var less = [];
   var more = [];
   var equals = [];

   //Find a rough median
   if (arr.length > 1){
       var pivot = arr[Math.floor((arr.length/2))];

       for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
         if (arr[i] < pivot){
              less.push(arr[i]);
         }
         else if (arr[i] == pivot){
              equals.push(arr[i]);
         }
         else if (arr[i] > pivot){
              more.push(arr[i]);
         }
        }

       quickSort(less);quickSort(more);
       return less.concat(equals,more); 
   }
}
```

I passed in the unordered float list = `[3, 4, 54, 6, 6, 4, 3, 2, 2]`

And it output this `[3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 6, 6, 54]` clearly not considering a couple of cases. What's going on?

Comment: should be `less = quicksort(less)` ... as your sort is not inplace, but rather returns a new sorted array.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, also had to add an else condition to deal with the case that has an array of size 1.

Comment: @JLRishe I suppose see how it would be O( n^2 ). It keeps divvying up the array and then iterating over each of those pieces. So is the link here wrong? http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort

It shows me a in-place solution after the pseudocode for the solution I just implemented and notes that the only difference between the two is the memory intensiveness because of the new array creation.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thinking thoroughly enough. After thinking through it more, I think it is correct. I'm going to delete my prior comment. Like most quicksorts, it can be N^2 if bad pivots are chosen, but won't necessarily be N^2.